# how can I activate the edit button? mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I got this error
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "details5f9c3b069dc8723528c64cc8" at path "_id" for model "Book"

the edit and delete button are not activated.

Help me to figure it out please. this is /routes/books.js

and what else do I upload here?

```js
// GET edit an existing Book
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  
  book.findById(id, (err, bookToEdit) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      //res.end(err);
    } else {
      //show the edit view
      res.render('books/details', {title: 'Edit Book', books: bookToEdit})
    }
  });
});

// POST and update the document
router.post('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id
  
  let updatedBook = book({
    _id: id,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    price: req.body.price,
    author: req.body.author,
    genre: req.body.genre
  });

  book.updateOne({_id: id}, updatedBook, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      // refresh
      res.redirect('/books');
    }
  });
});

// GET - process the delete by user id
router.get('/delete/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id;

  book.remove({_id: id}, (err) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end(err);
    } else {
      // refresh
      res.redirect('/books');
    }
  });
});
```

This is /books/details.ejs

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <form class="form" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="TitleTextField">Title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="TitleTextField"
                placeholder="Book Title" name="title" value="<%= books.Title %>" required>
              </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <label for="AuthorTextField">Author</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="AuthorTextField"
                placeholder="Book Author" name="author" value="<%= books.Author %>"  required>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PriceTextField">Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PriceTextField"
                placeholder="Book Price" name="price" value="<%= books.Price %>"  required>
              </div>
              
             

      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is /books/indexejs

```html
<% include ../partials/header.ejs %>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

<!--Add-->

          <a href="/books/add" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add a book</a>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Author</th>
                  <th class ="col-4">Price</th>


                  <th class="text-center">EDIT</th>
                  <th class="text-center">DELETE</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <% for (let count = 0; count < books.length; count++) { %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= books[count].Title %></td>
<td class="text-center"><%= books[count].Author %></td>
                  <td class="text-center">$<%= books[count].Price %></td>
                  <!--EDIT-->

                  </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                      <a href="/books/edit<%= books[count].id %>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
                    </td>

<!--DELETE-->
                    <td class="text-center">
                      <a href="/books/delete<%= books[count].id %>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a></td>

                  </td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

this is    /models/books.js

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Book = mongoose.Schema({
  
    Title: String,
    Description: String,
    Price: Number,
    Author: String,
    Genre: String
},
{
  collection: "books"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', Book);
```

hope these are helpful to fix the problems

Comment: `_id` is populated for you my MongoDB. If you need a specific ID to be placed onto the document being stored, create a Model property called `id` (no underscore). Then set your `id` into the models `id` rather then `_id`

Comment: @RandyCasburn okay that's a great idea. it will be better to work. what about solutions?

Comment: "_what about soluitons?_" ----- I said this: "If you need a specific ID to be placed onto the document being stored, create a Model property called id (no underscore). Then set your id into the models id rather then _id"

Answer (score 1):

You have an error that said that book.find and book.delete need an ObjectId as parameter. And `details5f9c3b069dc8723528c64cc8` is not a valid ObjectId for Mongo.

Just read the error message !

**Edition**

Maybe you face this problem because you made a little mistake with resources, using same http POST to create and edit, giving the :id in path in both case.

If you have a POST / (no id in path) method to create books, letting mongodb generate ids, and have a PATCH (or PUT) /:id method to update those books, you probably will not have this kind of error anymore.

It will maybe sounds like stupid duplication but as your app will grow, you certainly will need to add some specific security rules.

Also, if I remember mongoose correctly, you're not supposed update the _id in second parameter for updateOne.

```
//no _id present in updatedBook
book.updateOne({_id: id}, updatedBook, (err) => { };
```

Comment: It should be clear the OP didn't understand the meaning of the at obscure error. While somewhat caustic, this answer isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The default key of a document in MongoDB is `_id` who set an ObjectId in it.
ObjectId is a unique key who contained from some meaningful base on date and time (you can convert objectId to date).
You can read more about it [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/objectid/#:%7E:text=An%20ObjectId%20is%20a%2012,them%20using%20a%20default%20Algorithm.).

And your problem, it's really easy. You concat your ObjectId with details as you can see in the error.

`details5f9c3b069dc8723528c64cc8` => `5f9c3b069dc8723528c64cc8`